# Confusion regarding html Web Audio Api and <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am a html5 newbie and have some confusions regarding the audio tag and web audio api.
I am currently working on a custom audio scrubber for our audio player. The scrubber will have a progress bar and some kind of time indicator. The user should be able to drag the progress bar and the audio will play.

The current audio player plays only a small chunk of mp3 at a time and then it is loaded periodically by sending a request to the server (polling). I understand using  tag you have to provide src but given that the small chunks are being loaded rather than 1 monolithic one I am also looking to see if I can capture events from the web audio api. The way way are creating and playing the audio is using web audio api in the following fashion:

```
soundSource = context.createBufferSource();
soundBuffer = context.createBuffer()
soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;
soundSource.connect(context.destination);
```

What I do not understand is the relationship between the audio tag and the destination node.

How can I direct the destination node to the audio tag? Can I capture events from the web audio api (play, pause, timeupdate)? Essentially I want to be able to write event listeners on a streaming audio player which plays in small chunks at a time and have them all tied to a custom slider. Can anyone help me or provide some pointers?

Gordon

Answer (score 3):

OK. I don't think you can can redirect the output of the `context.destination` to any other component. You can considered `context.destination` as the loudspeaker. Whatever you send to that gets played out immediately.

So there isn't much of a relationship between WebAudio API and the Audio tag. The Audio tag implementation in the various browsers might be actually using WebAudioAPI behind the scenes, but there isn't any public facing API to change the audio tag behaviour.

The Audio tag though supports all the [standard Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events.).

There is however a tiny bridge between the Audio tag and the WebAudio API. You can use the audio from the Audio tag as a source of audio in WebAudioAPI. This is the [context.createMediaElementSource API in WebAudio](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioContext-createMediaElementSource-MediaElementAudioSourceNode-HTMLMediaElement-mediaElement).

Finally, scrubbing. If you want to be able to scrub "realtime", you're gonna have to have the entire audio file in the memory. That way you can jump to the spot the user wants to scrub to almost instantaneously. With the `AudioBuffer` in your hand, you can use the ScriptProcessorNode to correct output chunks of audio based on the position of the slider.